# Running Excel Macro from VBScript Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am trying to print a file from a vbs script, and I am getting a subscript out of range. The macro works great when ran from excel.

The VBS script is:

```
   dim xlApp    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   
    xlApp.Application.Run "'C:\Users\jporter8\Documents\dashboard\testing.xlsm'!Module1.print_Test"     
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True     
    xlApp.Application.quit  
    set xlApp = Nothing
```

and the excel macro is:

```
Sub print_Test()
     Sheets("two").PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    MsgBox "Print successful"
End Sub
```

And the sheet I am trying to print is named "two"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this work around to open the workbook so that the sheet existed and wasn't out of range

```
dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\jporter8\Documents\dashboard\testing.xlsm", 0, true)
xlApp.Run "Module1.print_Test"
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
wscript.echo "Printed"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit
set xlApp = Nothing
set xlBook = Nothing
wscript.echo "Finished"
wscript.Quit
```